# How to format or parse SOAP primitive object

Tags: java, android, ios, regex, soap

**ANDROID**

I am getting the below response in my WSDL API:

> a:10:{s:11:"sso_user_id";s:6:"123345";s:9:"firstname";s:0:"";s:8:"lastname";s:0:"";s:5:"abono";s:0:"";s:4:"hash";s:32:"c2ff5bc4598d02160b57e2b3f28a3e0e";s:5:"token";s:32:"2da9ba3bcc52fdb047c3da5d91e3cdbd";s:5:"login";s:23:"sandor.fekete@inform.hu";s:6:"cookie";s:232:"";s:6:"access";a:1:{s:4:"role";s:2:"NO";}s:5:"error";s:0:"";}

I have taken the String between response tag,

Now here is info  about the response structure:

**s:11:"sso_user_id";**-
 sso_user_id is the key having the length of 11 character.

**s:6:"123345";**- 123345 is the value of sso_user_id having length of 6 character.

Now can anybody help me to **PARSE** or **FORMAT** or give **REGEXP** to make the normal String or easily understandable String.

**NOTE:- THIS IS NOT A JSON STRING.**

IOS code and logic also most welcome.

Comment: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html check this and next time try to make a call rather than posting in fb as you know i will not use it regularly

Comment: @KK_07k11A0585 Thnx, But I have resolved it using custom parsing. But Still the link u gave does the what I need? I will look in to it tomorrow. I will be posting my code later When I parse successfully all the data.

Comment: As semicolon is used as a separator, but is not escaped in the data, could you split the data on ";s:" and work from there?

Comment: Hi @ZlatinZlatev I have done the parsing... I will be posting code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to do this:

```
public static void parseSOAPPrimitiveObject(String input, Object output)
        throws NumberFormatException, IllegalArgumentException,
        IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

    Class theClass = output.getClass();
    Field[] fields = theClass.getDeclaredFields();

    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        Type type = fields[i].getType();
        fields[i].setAccessible(true);

        // detect String
        if (fields[i].getType().equals(String.class)) {
            String tag = "" + fields[i].getName() + "";
            if (input.contains(tag)) {
                String strValue = "";
                strValue = input.substring(input.indexOf(tag)
                        + tag.length() + 2);

                if (getValueLength(strValue) > 0) {
                    strValue = getValue(strValue);
                } else {
                    strValue = "";
                }

                fields[i].set(output, strValue);
            }
        }

        // detect int or Integer
        if (type.equals(Integer.TYPE) || type.equals(Integer.class)) {
            String tag = "" + fields[i].getName() + "";
            if (input.contains(tag)) {
                String strValue = "";
                strValue = input.substring(input.indexOf(tag)
                        + tag.length() + 2);
                fields[i].set(output, getValueLengthInt(strValue));
            }
        }
    }
}

public static String getValue(String substring) {

    String str = new String(substring);

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(.+?)\"");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    matcher.find();

    return matcher.group(0);
}

public static int getValueLength(String substring) {

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":(.+?):");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(substring);
    matcher.find();
    int count = 0;

    count = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));

    return count;
}

public static int getValueLengthInt(String substring) {

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":(.+?);");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(substring);
    matcher.find();
    int count = 0;

    count = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));

    return count;
}
```

Class for Object:

```
public class SSOuser {

String  sso_user_id;
String  firstname;
String  lastname;
String  abono;
String  hash;
String  token;
String  login;

String  cookie;

String  role;
String  error;

}
```

To show Data:

```
SSOuser ouser = getFormatedResponseData(result.toString());
String finalValues = "";                                    
finalValues = finalValues + "\n" + "fname= " + ouser.firstname;
finalValues = finalValues + "\n" + "lastname= " + ouser.lastname;
finalValues = finalValues + "\n" + "abono= " + ouser.abono;
finalValues = finalValues + "\n" + "hash= " + ouser.hash;
finalValues = finalValues + "\n" + "role= " + ouser.role;
finalValues = finalValues + "\n" + "sso_user_id= " + ouser.sso_user_id;
finalValues = finalValues + "\n" + "token= " + ouser.token;
finalValues = finalValues + "\n" + "login= " + ouser.login;
finalValues = finalValues + "\n" + "error= " + ouser.error;
// finalValues=finalValues+
// "\n"+"cookie= " + output.cookie;
final String val = finalValues;

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    txtValues.setText(val);}});
```